Can different cores (or hardware threads within cores) in a multi-core processor with SMT/hyper-threading operate at different IRQLs simultaneously?
I'm wondering if it is possible to have Thread 1 running with IRQL 2 on the core 1 and have Thread 2 running on core 1 with IRQL 0 at the same time.
Also I'm wondering if the above possible for two different cores
